# big image slowing Polaroid effect in gallery in chrome

Tags: php, image

i m making a Polaroid image gallery and for which i have used dynamic images from database . all the images are of 1024*800 resolution . for some reason i dont knw why the Polaroid effect is way 2 slow in gallery in chrome . in firefox its working fine.

i used

```
   <img src="<?php echo $pic;?>"  width="160" height="160" title="Click To View" onclick="sendpic('<?php echo $picID;?>');"/></a>
```

and the image got resized but this new problem exist . polaroid effect (ie little image zoom )
is taking decades to show up but same thing is working so perfect in firefox . can anyone help me with this why is it so ????

Comment: html resizing is not the same as image resizing, the image file would still be as big as the original

Comment: then how to solve this problem friend can you suggest something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if its working perfect in firefox thn i think issue can be in its CSS.. 
Try using this CSS...

```
a:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.25); // For Chrome & Safari
-moz-transform: scale(1.25);  // For Mozilla
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Hope it wrks fine... :)

Comment: hello , i found out the isse its not the issue of css , its due to the large image resize of html resizing . well have to put ou thumbnails instead